# Android: Replacing text in field with "Intent.putExtra()" fails in Messenger app

Tags: java, android, action

I am trying to use `android.intent.action.PROCESS_TEXT` to update text in any app's input field when the user opts to do so. The problem is that within some apps the change is not applied despite the fact that I can confirm that the action was triggered, the text was parsed, and my method completed successfully.

I have the following in my manifest:

```
        <activity
            android:name=".ProcessTextDefaultActivity"
            android:label="@string/menuitem_process_text_default">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PROCESS_TEXT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

And the following relevant method:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (isProcessTextActionCompatible()) return;

    boolean isReadOnly = getIntent()
            .getBooleanExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PROCESS_TEXT_READONLY, false);

    CharSequence inputText = getIntent()
            .getCharSequenceExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PROCESS_TEXT);

    String outputText = inputText.toString();
    // Replace characters in string as needed
    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : dictionary.entrySet()) {
        outputText = outputText.replace(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
    }


    if (isReadOnly) {
        // Custom method to copy the input to the user clipboard
        copyString(outputText);
        return;
    }

    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PROCESS_TEXT, outputText);
    setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
    finish();
}
```

Comment: Problems exists on different apps on the same android OS version? On what version did You checked it ?

Comment: Yes, this occurs for apps on the same Android OS version. I am testing on Android 9. I assumed that this functionality works the same way that Android's "paste" works. However, using the Messenger app as an example, Paste works but my `setResult()` does not. Because I think that React Native apps usually have state-manage fields and that this *may* be the cause, I am wondering if I can trigger an update on the field within my intent (like firing KeyUp). Is that reasonable?